# Attempting to print non-ASCII UTF-8 characters in Xcode in C language (not C++, not Objective C) on MacBook 10.6.8

Tags: c, xcode, utf-8

So far I have not found any example pieces of code that allow me to successfully print (printf) non-ASCII UTF-8 codes using this MacBook 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo w 10.6.8 / Xcode / C (NOT C++, NOT Objective C).

Here is what code I can point to as not doing what I want:
Also the output:
And output of locale if that matters:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
printf ("%s\n", "ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü");
//printf ("%lu\n", (long unsigned int)strlen ("ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü"));
//printf ("%d\n", (int) strlen ("ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü"));
char bytes[] = "s\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x87\xaa\xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0    \x9f\x98\x82\xc3\xa0";
printf("'%s'\n", bytes);
printf("-----%lc------", (wchar_t)0x3041);
printf ("%s\n", "ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü");
}

$ gcc -o AttemptingUTF8.x AttemptingUTF8.c 
$ ./AttemptingUTF8.x 
ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü
'sà'
ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

19:37 added to code:
    char byte[]="\xc2\xab";// double arrow to left
    printf("%s\n",byte);
    char byteAE[]="\xc7\xbc";// AE
    printf("%s\n",byteAE);
With added output:
    «
    Ǽ

Which I do see, and which does answer the problem. So thank you for the responses.

Comment: C does not support a specific character set apart from ASCII: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1. However, it is a matter of the libraries to interpret UTF-8 encoding. You also have to set the source and target character set when compiling.

Comment: However: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: As zaph's "answer" below indicates, there's no complication with outputting UTF-8 via `printf()`. If you have a character buffer whose content is a null-terminated sequence of UTF-8 code units, you can just print it and your program is outputting UTF-8. It's then up to the recipient as to how that UTF-8 is handled. For example, a Terminal window should interpret it just fine and show the corresponding characters. You will have to be a lot clearer about why you think it's a problem to print UTF-8 characters.

Comment: *"So I am attempting to resort to compiling the free public domain code"*. Yeah, that was a really bad idea. You should have asked here first, before going off into the weeds. I suggest that you edit the question to remove everything after the first paragraph. And then explain exactly what you're trying to do, and show the code that you tried. There is absolutely nothing hard about printing UTF-8 strings in C on a MAC using Xcode.

Comment: BTW, Apple no longer supplies gcc as part of Xcode, where did you get gcc?

Comment: $ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Xcode 
version 3.2.6
64-bit
Component versions
Xcode IDE: 1761.0
Xcode Core: 1809.0
ToolSupport: 1806.0
Copyright © 1999-2010 Apple Inc.

Comment: @Olaf Disagree with "C does not support a specific character set apart from ASCII".  ASCII is not specified in C11, although using ASCII poses few problems.  It is all but specified.

Comment: In the question update output I see all the characters correctly. You should too in your browser. Hint: You can delete your comments like the comments that are the same as the update to the question.

Comment: I'm seeing three correct lines of output. (The missing line is the line that uses `%lc` with the `(wchar_t)0x3041`). Are you seeing the correct output for the three lines?

Comment: The umlaut characters show up just fine in Terminal. So, some UTF-8 characters can be displayed in Terminal, if they are handed over through a print statement. But I cannot yet know a way to Make them show up through virtue of coding their UTF-8 codes.

The codes like x98\x82 do nothing in Terminal but show up as empty squares. 

Both Safari and Firefox when viewing page http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f602/browsertest.htm do not display Decimal escape, Hex escape, or UTF-8. (So then is there a UTF-8 problem if umlaut characters can show up in Terminal?)

Comment: @chux: Point taken. I should have written "C does not support characters other than those provided by ASCII and some other basic character encodings for `char`" (Just curious: is there still any other encoding being broadly used?). There is a reason the linked paragraph is longer than a SO comment. Basically C only uses the lower 128 **binary** codes of a `char` and leaves the higher codes to the user/libraries/OS. (This is the reason why the signedness of a `char` was not much of a problem when C was defined; other languages were simply ignored.

Comment: @Olaf 2 contenders: [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and variations on ASCII - all fading.  C does not use all 128 ASCII.  IMO, in 10 years there will only be UTF-8 and "legacy" encodings.

Comment: @chux: "Variations on ASCII? If you think about using code 128-255 of an octet (like ISO-8859 family, the windows-encodings, etc.: These I excluded, because they are actually not ASCII anymore. About the obsolescencce in 5-10 years, I would be very careful; the same was ASCII supposed to, same as C, Cobol, Fortran, etc. Programmers are quite conservative. And for embedded systems a fixed-size code has many advantages, of course and is often sufficient. But interesting EBCDIC is still alive and even got CPU-support for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Test with UTF-8, Xcode, "C", command line project:

```
char bytes[] = "s\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x87\xaa\xf0\x9f\x87\xb8\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xc3\xa0";
printf("'%s'\n", bytes);
```

Output:

> 'sà'

That is about worse case, emoji and a flag.

The characters in the string are: LATIN SMALL LETTER S, FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY, REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER E, FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY, LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE.

Comment: That snippet of code gives output as follows:'sà'
I see squares with little numbers and letters inside, and I do not know if that is a failing of my browser.

Comment: Could be your browser, which one are you using? I see the characters in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Do you have a special font selected?

Comment: Firefox 40.0.3, (Preferences) default is Times, font size 24. (Advanced) Fonts for : Latin, Proportional: Serif, Serif: Times, Sans-serif: Helvetica, Monospace: Courier

Comment: Best guess is that your computer has a font problem. Added the names of the characters in the string to the answer..

Comment: That gives me something diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The umlaut characters `"ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü"` correspond to code points 0xC4, 0xCB, 0xCF, 0xD6, 0xDC, 0xE4, 0xEB, 0xEF, 0xF6, and 0xFC as shown in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout).

However, those are not the UTF-8 encodings of the characters. They must be converted to UTF-8 as described in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which has this very helpful table<sup>*</sup>

[image]

*<sub>Note that the last two rows are no longer used, see the wikipedia article for details.</sub>

To encode the umlaut-A in UTF-8, you begin with the raw code, which is 0xC4. That falls in the range of the second row of the table. So we must split the value into two parts and encode it in two bytes.

```
       11000100        0xC4
      11    000100     split into high and low parts
   00011    000100     pad the high part to 5 bits
11000011  10000100     insert the UTF-8 bits from row 2 of the table
  0xC3      0x84       the two byte UTF-8 encoding of the umlaut A
```

Here's the code to output the UTF-8 using C code

```
int main( void )
{
    char str[] = { 0xC3, 0x84, 0x00 };
    printf( "%s\n", str );
}
```

OTOH, if you copy/paste the umlaut-A into the code, then Xcode will automatically convert it to UTF-8, which you can demonstrate with this code

```
int main( void )
{
    char *str = "Ä";
    for ( int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        printf( "0x%02X ", str[i] & 0xff );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

which should print `0xC3 0x84`.

Comment: 5 and 6 byte representations are not UTF-8. From the referenced Wikipedia: "The original specification covered numbers up to 31 bits (the original limit of the Universal Character Set). In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to end at U+10FFFF, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding. This removed all 5- and 6-byte sequences, and 983040 4-byte sequences." Providing the table as UTF-8 is incorrect, unicode is a 21-bit encoding, see [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629), also see [The Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org).

Comment: Note, the reference to "umlaut characters" is incorrect, these are "diacritical marks", an umlaut is just one of many diacritical marks. Further those mentioned are just the ones on code-points in the range U+0080 - U+00FF, there are hundreds of characters with diacritical marks outside that range of code-points.

Comment: *"The [diaeresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)), also spelled diæresis or dieresis and **also known as** the trema or **the umlaut**, is a diacritical mark that consists of two dots ( ¨ ) placed over a letter, usually a vowel."* I used the term *umlaut* because that was the term used by the OP. The code points I listed are all umlaut characters. There may be more, but those are the umlaut characters listed in the question.

Comment: Given that unicode is a 21-bit encoding, the last two rows of the table are not necessary, but they do not detract from the validity of the table. The table can be used to correctly encode any of the code points of the 21-bit unicode encoding.

Comment: The title of the question and the tags narrow the scope of the question to the C language with Xcode on a MAC. Nothing in my answer was intended to expand the scope of the question. In short, thanks for posting a whole bunch of nitpicks that have nothing to do with the substance of my answer.

Comment: You might consider correcting the answer to remove the "nitpicks" such as the lUTF-8 table which included 5 & 6 byte entries..